# HTML background image does not scroll

Tags: html, css, background

Have a look at this page: [rozbub](http://www.magnavoce.ch/rozbub)

As you see, there is a fix header on the top and a scrollable content below. The content inside the black div scrolls well, but the image is fixed. How can I let this image scroll too?

Basically, I defined the main wrappers as following:

```
body{
    width: 100%;   
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}

#generalWrapper{
    height: 100%;
}

#header{
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #080808;
}

#content{
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url("../images/background.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

with a structure like

```
<body>
    <generalWrapper>
        <header>
        </header>
        <content>
        </content>
    </generalWrapper>
</body>
```

Then, the content `div` is filled with elements (which make this `div` taller than the screen and results in scrollability). But why is the background image not affected?

Comment: You might want to consider using a wider background image. I'm on a 2560px-wide monitor, and the background only takes up about 3/4 of the width of my screen; the rest is a solid white background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a different approach. First of all, I put the background image on the html, with following attributes

```
html{
    background: url("../background.jpg") center center #000; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Then, I changed the header and content to

```
#header{
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #080808;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 55;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #080808;
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

which results in exactly that behaviour I desired (Although the problem considered by Jules Mazur in the comment is not solved, I will try to solve this by providing different images for different resolutions).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are scrolling `div`s inside your `content` `div`, but the `content` `div` itself is not scrolled. 
Try to look through the list of errors found on your site by [W3C's Markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://magnavoce.ch/rozbub/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `background-attacment` to `scroll`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) has documentation for this property.

Comment: Jules, I would advise against using W3Schools for any technical reference, if needed use a more valid source such as MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/background here is why W3Schools should be avoided http://w3fools.com/

Comment: leopic, That website doesn't make any mention why W3Schools should be avoided. What is so "unreputable" about W3Sschools. At least 4 years later it's still showing up at the top of google search results so what does that say?

Comment: @thefoyer popularity is not an index of reliability. W3Schools is consistently out of date and frequently wrong. After 4 more years of being involved in programming, I can honestly say that MDN is the _de facto_ authority when it comes to high-quality web standards documentation.

Comment: @Jules I'm sorry but I still don't think this is a good enough answer for stack overflow. You're making claims but I have seen no proof. I'd love to have some though for future reference is the point but we can't just believe everything we hear.

Comment: @thefoyer the claims are in the comments. The answer is now as unopinionated as it can reasonably be, refers to what's widely recognized as a reputable source (MDN), and directly addresses the question. In any case, this issue is 4 years old, and long since solved; I'm not sure why you're apparently so determined to discredit this (still valid, but non-selected) answer.

Comment: @Jules the answer is fine it's just I thought it was interesting that 4 years ago W3schools was the top result for queries and it still is today. When supposedly MDN is the go to. Just interesting and I want it backed up by facts not claims.

Comment: This does not detract from the quality or accuracy of the answer and is a borderline political/favouritist issue (and in either case, _completely_ off-topic on StackOverflow).